# How to detect if the React app is actually being viewed

Tags: reactjs

So I have created an app that shows data in realtime obtaining it from devices.
However, I want to make my server not obtain data when nobody is viewing the app.
So essentially I need some way to determine whether the app is currently being viewed, regardless of if it's desktop or mobile, this includes tab is on focus where the app is opened and that is what the user is currently viewing, and there is nothing on top of the browser, so browser opened on the correct tab, but user has explorer on top of it doing something entirely different, this for my case should be `false`, and for mobile, the same thing including if device is locked (screen off).

The reason for trying to do that, is to reduce the load on the devices, so that data is being requested, only when there is someone to view it.

From what I have researched I found out about the `focus` and `blur` events, but I was unable to make it work, and I don't even know if that is the correct approach, but what I have tried is:

Adding event listeners to the window in the App component:

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("focus", () => { console.log("viewed")});
    window.addEventListener("blur", () => { console.log("hidden")});
  })
}
```

Adding them as props to the App component within index.js:

```
<App onFocus={() => {console.log("viewed")}} onBlur={() => {console.log("hidden")}}/>
```

Neither had any kind of effect, I didn't get either of the console outputs.

Is that even the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving it with pretty much the same code as initiallywith a few slight modifications, I still used an `useEffect` hook:

```
 const onFocusFunction = () => {
    // do whatever when focus is gained
  };

 const onBlurFunction = () => {
   // do whatever when focus is lost
 };

 useEffect(() => {
   onFocusFunction();

   window.addEventListener("focus", onFocusFunction);
   window.addEventListener("blur", onBlurFunction);

   return () => {
     onBlurFunction();

     window.removeEventListener("focus", onFocusFunction);
     window.removeEventListener("blur", onBlurFunction);
   };
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a socket connection to the app. Then the server would be able to know if there are at least X persons connected and act accordingly.

Comment: I already have a socket connection to the app, but that doesnt get the job done. It can only detect if someone is connected or disconnected. Switching to another tab, is not disconnecting the user, so it is not going to work

Comment: Yes, it could work. You could have a useeffect that would kill the socket if the user goes to another tab with document.hasFocus().

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try socket for this kind of connection tested, but since you also wanna reduce the load for the user, testing if the user is focused in the browser is the way to go.

To achieve it, I won't add this code inside the React component because of the nature of React as all of its components are rendered inside the `<div id="root"></div>`, other parts of the html page will still be unaffected by this mechanism. So what you probably want to do is to add the code in the `index.html` and use `window.userFocused` to pass the value into React from the index

---

Edit: added focus/blur script

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("focus", function(event) 
    { 
        console.log("window is focused");
        window.userFocused = true;
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("blur", function(event) 
    { 
        console.log("window is blurred");
        window.userFocused = false;
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I cant find any information about `window.userFocused`

Comment: sorry that's just a variable name I just came up, you can store if the user focus in this variable and pass it into React

Comment: Okay, but lets go back to, how do I determine if the window is viewed or not in the first place?

Comment: I added the script for focus/blur and tested it using the developer console. You can also try to manually add it in the browser and see if it works for you first

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use document.

```
 document.onvisibilitychange = () => {
   console.log(document.hidden)
 }
```